# 'gcc.exe' failed in phase 'Assembler' while running Haskell code

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following Haskell code which simply displays the sum, difference, product, and quotient of two numbers, along with the range of numbers from 1 to 10 and the letters.

```
main = do

    let a = 5
    let b = 10
    
    putStrLn "The addition of the two numbers is: "
    print(a + b);
    
    putStrLn "The subtraction of the two numbers is: "
    print(a - b);
    
    putStrLn "The multiplication of the two numbers is: "
    print(a * b);
    
    putStrLn "The division of the two numbers is: "
    print(a * b);
    
    print [1..10]
    print ['a'..'z']
```

I ran it on an online compiler and it seemed to work, but when I pasted it on Notepad and ran it through Terminal, it showed the error:

```
Fatal error: can't create basicOperators.o: No such file or directory
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Assembler'. (Exit code: 1)
```

This is interesting because I have GHC installed on my computer and the Haskell compiler was working just fine a few days ago, but now it stopped working. I am still a beginner at Haskell and I need a hand on how I can avoid getting this error. I will appreciate it if someone has an idea.

Comment: Verify that you are running your compilation command in an existing writable folder.

Comment: I just tried removing the folder with my program and then remade the folder along with copy-pasted the code into a new notepad document and put it in the new folder, and now it gave me this error. proof of command in writable folder = https://prnt.sc/vrwxz0 and error = https://prnt.sc/vrwybb

Comment: Obviously ghc cannot see or access your folder for some reason, or perhaps an antivirus interferes with the normal operation. Try doing the same thing in `c:\temp` and/or disable the antivirus. You should be aware that Windows seems to be a second-priority OS for GHC developers and Haskell ecosystem in general.

Comment: I tried looking for the c:\temp folder but I couldn't find it to save my program in.

Comment: Nevermind, I went to the C:\ folder and created a new folder named temp, and I put my program in that folder. It works now, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @n. 'pronouns' m commented, GHC seems to have a problem writing to this folder. Try using a different folder, for example creating `C:\Temp`, copying over your code and compiling from there.